# Help ! What is the equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $2$ Variables:

1. Job ($A, B, C$)
2. Age (Young, Adult, Old)

Total population for job is $100$,
total population for age is $100$

Job $A$ has $20\%$ of population

Job $B$: $30\%$

Job $C$: $50\%$

Young age is $10\%$ of population

Adult: $50\%$

Old: $40\%$

Young Age only working in Job $A$ & $B$
Adult only working in Job $A$ & $C$
Old only working in Job $B$ & $C$

How could I find the right number for each intersection of these variables? What is the equation?

If I count it manually, I'll find:

1. Young age in Job $A$: $4$ people
2. Young age, Job $B$: $6$
3. Adult, Job $A$: $16$
4. Adult, Job $C$: $34$
5. Old, Job $B$: $24$
6. Old, Job $C$: $16$

Comment: This is not differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a grid to show the data you are given.  The numbers on the borders are the sums of the rows or columns.  You can put a $0$ in the cells that you know do not have anybody in them.  Now you can put a variable in each blank cell.  From the two in the A row you get an equation $a+b=20$.

[image]

You can write six equations in six unknowns.  Unfortunately there is a dependence between them, so there is not a single solution.  You can see this because $a,d,e=1, b,c,f=-1$ would sum to zero in all the edge cells, so you can add or subtract any multiple of this (until some variable goes below $0$) and get another solution.

Another solution besides the one you found is
1. Young age in Job $A$: $3$ people
2. Young age, Job $B$: $7$
3. Adult, Job $A$: $17$
4. Adult, Job $C$: $33$
5. Old, Job $B$: $23$
6. Old, Job $C$: $17$